# Need app to read Eudora mail (that mailbox file format)

Tags: email, eudora

I was unable to successfully copy my 20 years of Eudora emails to Thunderbird.  The process is difficult to follow & just seems to hang.

There must be a simple app that will allow me to open a Eudora mailbox folder, and select an email from an index list, and read the contents.  Its just a "flat file" with a marker to separate each email.  And maybe a separate toc (table of contents) file with the header data and a pointer to the location in the flat file.

And somebody please create the tag "Eudora"

Comment: I can still run Eudora since I'm using OSX 10.6.8, but newer OS will not run Eudora.  And I really need to try upgrading since the I think the outdated Quicktime & Java are making FireFox & Safari run uselessly slowly.

Comment: Did you already try [Eudora Mailbox Cleaner](http://andreasamann.com/MacOSX/Eudora_Mailbox_Cleaner)? Please add the content of you comment to your question by editing the latter with the [edit link](http://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/177977/edit) right below the tag "email". Then delete your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Please download [Eudora Mailbox Cleaner](http://andreasamann.com/MacOSX/Eudora_Mailbox_Cleaner), and install it. The app may export mailboxes from Eudora to Thunderbird or Apple Mail with less restrictions or drawbacks than directly importing them in Thunderbird. Additionally you may export them from Thunderbird to Apple Mail.

System requirement: Mac OS X 10.2 - Mac OS X 10.6.8 (with Rosetta installed)

Please check the limitation mentioned on the page thoroughly (especially the 2 GB mailbox limit - and how to circumvent it).